# Does Java 8, Wildfly Server, IntelliJ Idea work on Window 10 Home Edition

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, java-8, wildfly

Kindly help me to know. Does Java 8, Wildfly Server, IntelliJ Idea work on Window 10 Home Edition? I am going to buy a laptop with Window 10 Home Edition.
Thanks please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason it shouldn't. Java runs just fine on Windows home editions, and that's really all you need.

I haven't tried to run Wildfly on Windows 10, but Java 8 and IntelliJ I have run, as well as other application servers like WebLogic, Tomcat, Jetty, and Glassfish, and they run without problems.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, since the windows version doesn't restrict the use of such software.
To get an overview what each windows version is capable of take a look at this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Comparison_chart